# got or went burgled

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context, word-in-context

Could anybody please help me to identify if there is a difference between the meaning of the following two sentences? Or do both the sentences convey the same meaning?

1. Our house ***got*** burgled.
2. Our house ***went*** burgled.

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen *went burgled*.  Using *went* in such a way is not idiomatic. Here's the ones I can think of:

> went... hungry, crazy, south, away, missing, "the way of" (the dinosaurs, etc.)

A few of those have in common that the action occurs due to neglect of some sort, and your house might be burgled because you are not there, but it sounds very odd to native speakers to say it that way.

Also - *was burgled* is good.